# Creating language pack as addon Installshield 2011

Tags: installshield-2011

I would like to create the language pack as add-on to my application which should act like a update to my older installation.

It has to copy a folder to already installed location. this add on size should not be more than 2 or 3 mb.

I am using installshiled 2011 and my project type is Basic MSI. I have already released my application with only English. Now whatever the language pack I am going to create that should be in the same language (for ex if I create German language pack that should be in German)

Form one of the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969379.aspx#Filtering_Add_Remove_Programs) link I found we can register the application as update to our project. However I could not able to do that. If any body has better idea on this let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For someone who may interested to do like this.

I could able to create the language pack as a separate installation, I am not writing any registry entry for that installation (I removed those sequences). Form the script I am finding my main installation's install directory and setting the INSTALLDIR for my language pack installation.. So it does just a shadow copy of my language files.

This is how I solved it..